# Julia: How to do an "as of" merge?

Tags: algorithm, julia

Simple question: I would like to understand if Julia has a function to merge "as of"[1] two dataframes, or if not how would could implement it.

[1] merge "as of" in the style of pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

EDIT: Here's one example

```
left = DataFrame(Dict(:timestamp=>[100,200,300,400]))
right = DataFrame(Dict(:timestamp=>[94, 150, 200, 201, 299, 300, 301, 401], :v=>1:8))
```

The output should be a `DataFrame` like

```
DataFrame(Dict(:timestamp=>[100,200,300,400], :v=>[1,3,6,7]))
```

I ended up with the following implementation which works for my case but I'm sure is not as robust or general as it could be (lets assume timestamp cols are sorted):

```
function mergeasof(left::DataFrame, right::DataFrame, right_col::String)
    @assert "timestamp" in names(left)
    @assert "timestamp" in names(right)
    @assert right_col in names(right)
    i = 1
    j = 1
    left = copy(left)
    left[!, right_col] = Array{eltype(right[right_col])}(undef, size(left,1));
    for j in 1:size(right, 1)
        if i < size(left, 1)
            while right.timestamp[j] > left.timestamp[i]
                i += 1
                if i == size(left, 1) break end
            end
            left[!, right_col][i] = right[!, right_col][j]
        end
    end
    left
end
```

For example, straight away you can see an edge can which isn't covered: if `left` contains timestamps earlier than the earliest timestamps in `right`, then in the merged table you should have some missing values. But that means that setting the type with `left[!, right_col] = Array{eltype(right[right_col])}(undef, size(left,1));` is wrong. Also this isn't as efficient as it could be if we had an index on the timestamps.

Comment: not relevant to pandas, removing tag

Comment: There is no such function in DataFrames.jl. In general it would be more problematic than in Pandas to have it, as we are very flexible what you can store in columns (so often the values you store do not have a notion of "distance" between them). Can you please give a reproducible example of your problem and precisely specified task and I can propose an efficient solution.

Comment: Hello Bogumil, thank you for your work :-) I have updated my question for the sake of completeness, but you shouldn't worry about this. I have a solution that works for my use case. I was just asking because I was surprised that I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Comment: Note that unlike Python (or R) where `asof` joins are necessary because it would be slow to do a join + ordering and then cascade the last value down the data frame with a for loop, in Julia that is perfectly reasonable and fast, so perhaps that's a good approach.

Comment: I'm surprised that DataFrames.jl or some other Julia library doesn't have a function similar to pandas.merge_asof or rolling joins in the R data.table library.  I would expect these to be very useful in time series applications like trading.

Comment: In https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/issues/173, I describe a similar problem to this one.

Comment: https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/discussions/3207 refers to database systems that have dedicated syntax for "asof" joins and claims that these types of joins are ubiquitous in financial applications.